My if statement is not being triggered after explicitly being true
I have declared a private int called moveType at the top of my code & initialised it to 0 in the main movement script, SnakeMovement. I have then created a function called HorizontalMovement that is triggered when a GUI is clicked using the built-in OnClick function that comes with the text button. Once clicked, the moveType is changed to 1 which is intended to trigger an if statement in FixedUpdate() that will allow the player to use the A and D keys to move. However, despite the moveType successfully changing to 1, the if statement seems to not be triggered.
The weird thing is though, is that my MouseMovement code still appears to work using the same system. The only difference being their is some additional code in a separate script called MousePosition that gets the position of the mouse & returns it.
Note: The code inside the if statement 'if (moveType == 1)' has already been tested and worked perfectly fine when outside the if statement.
I have attatched both scripts below & as far as I'm aware the error is not triggered by an error in the inspector.
I have kept all the code in these scripts for better understanding of what the code is doing & so you can possibly see if a different area other than FixedUpdate() and HorizontalMovement() is causing the issue.
MousePosition Code:
public class MousePosition : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Camera mainCam;

    private void Start()
    {
        mainCam = Camera.main;
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Vector2 mouseWorldPosition = mainCam.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        transform.position = mouseWorldPosition;
    }
}

SnakeMovement Code:
public class SnakeMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public SnakeTail tail;

    [SerializeField] private GameObject moveObjScreen;
    [SerializeField] private GameObject mouse;
    private Camera mainCam;

    [SerializeField] private float speed;
    private float rotateSpeed;
    private float velocityX = 0f;
    private int moveType = 0;

    void Start()
    {
        Time.timeScale = 0;
        mainCam = Camera.main;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.LeftShift))
        {
            speed = 4.5f;
        }

        if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.LeftShift))
        {
            speed = 3f;
        }
    }
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        if (moveType == 1)
        {
            // Move Type
            velocityX = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");

            // Movement
            transform. Translate(Vector2.up * speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime, Space.Self);

            // Rotation
            transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward * -velocityX * rotateSpeed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
        }

        else if (moveType == 2)
        {
            FollowMousePosition();
        }
    }

    void HorizontalMovement()
    {
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
        moveObjScreen.SetActive(false);
        Time.timeScale = 1;
        moveType = 1;
    }

    private void MouseMovement()
    {
        Cursor.visible = false;
        moveObjScreen.SetActive(false);
        mouse.SetActive(true);
        Time.timeScale = 1;
        moveType = 2;
    }

    private void FollowMousePosition()
    {
        // Movement & Rotation
        transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, GetWorldPositionFromMouse(), speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    private Vector2 GetWorldPositionFromMouse()
    {
        return (mainCam.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition));
    }
}

Firstly, I tried to fix this by making both HorizontalMovement() & FixedUpdate() public as I thought it was an issue with variable scope. However, this did nothing so I serialized moveType to see what value it held once the HorizontalMovement GUI was pressed, and sure enough it said 1 but didn't seem to trigger the code inside the if statement. After this, I checked the inspector to see if there was anything missing or in the wrong place, in which I found nothing.

None of that should be in FixedUpdate, move it all to Update and change fixedDeltaTime to deltaTime.

Debug your code .. either log things or use breakpoints... c# doesn't just mess up if checks selectively .. if it behaves unexpectedly debug and find out why

Please share the inspector and hierarchy setup related to this functionality.
